# Defining structure in c socket program

Tags: c, sockets

```
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 1024, 0 , &saddr ,
                                           (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
```

here is a recvfrom function, where i want to create a struct to 'saddr' and 'saddr_size' which is declared in the main() as follows

```
struct sockaddr saddr;
int saddr_size;
saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
```

and instead of buffer mentioned in the below write() api i have to use the struct variable.

```
int cont= write(logfile,buffer,data_size);
```

My question is: Below i have used structure.Is this the way to define struct for the following fields? Is it declared correctly? if not please somebody guide me to correct it.

```
struct data{ 
  unsigned char buffer[1024];
  unsigned long int saddr; 
  //   struct sockaddr saddr;
  int saddr_size;
};
```

Comment: Read [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It saves you lots of time.

Comment: i have gone through that but have lots of doubt .so have uploaded my code for guidance

Comment: It should be `socklen_t sadd_size`. And, btw: `write()` returns `size_t`not `int`.

Comment: Why do you think this should be "correct"? You note yourself that `saddr` should be of `struct sockaddr` type and you have already been pointed to the fact that you should use `socklen_t` directly instead of using an `int` and abusing its address.

Comment: I am unclear what you're truing to do. If you just want a struct that has all of your data, sure, that's how you do it. Just put whatever 'variable' declarations you want inside the struct. If what you're trying to do is send a struct over the network, that's a much different question and is easily answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct data { 
  unsigned char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr saddr;
  socklen_t saddr_size;
};
```